# How can I check a string's pattern with given conditions (php/regex)

Tags: php, regex

This is what I'm trying to do,

```
   $line = "dsfsdf";
   if (!preg_match('/^(?=.{1,30}$)[a-zA-Z0-9\-\_]*$^/', $line))
   {
      echo 'No Match found';
   }
   else
   {
       echo 'Match found';
   }
```

The requirement is below,

- it can have characters
- it can have numbers
- As special character, it can have only hyphen (-)  and underscore (_) characters in it

I'm not so good at regex part. Can someone guide me how to achieve it with a simple explanation?

Comment: You must really remove `^` (start of string anchor) at the end. Try [`'/^[a-zA-Z0-9_-]{1,30}$/'`](https://ideone.com/T9hbjs). Or even `'/^[\w-]{1,30}$/'`

Comment: Thanks a lot.. it works like a charm. so, '\w-' includes all the alphanumeric character along with '-' and '_' ?

Comment: Yes, `\w` matches what `[a-zA-Z0-9_]` does if no `u` modifier is added. Please consider accepting my answer if it works for you.

Comment: one more thing, if there's one more condition that there should be white spaces then should i use '\s' ?

Comment: Yes, `\s` stands for whitespace. `[\w\s-]` will be the character class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must remove `^` (start of string anchor) at the end. Also, you may replace `[a-zA-Z0-9_]` with `\w`, as without any modifiers, they are equal.

The `(?=.{1,30}$)` lookahead makes the regex engine only match strings with 1 to 30 characters. You may remove the lookahead and just apply the limiting quantifier to your character class.

You may use

```
'/^[\w-]{1,30}$/'
```

If you prefer a more verbose way use

```
'/^[a-zA-Z0-9_-]{1,30}$/'
```

See the [PHP demo](https://ideone.com/T9hbjs).

Both mean:

- `^` - start of string
- `[\w-]{1,30}` - 1 to 30 letters/digits/underscores/`-` symbols
- `$` - end of string. **NOTE** that to match at the very end of the string, you need to use a `D` modifier, or replace `$` with `\z` anchor (i.e. use `'/^[\w-]{1,30}$/D'` or `'/^[\w-]{1,30}\z/'` then).

Comment: Thanks a lot for clarifying that in a very simple way

Comment: @DebrajDas If you can have a `\n` at the end of the input and if you do not want to allow matching this string, use `D` modifier.